# Properly escaping / formatting a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "  SELECT *
            FROM Catalog
            INTO OUTFILE './catalog.csv'
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
```

The error I get is that there is an issue with `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'`

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`

I've tried many different variations in the past hour such as using single quotes around the query and then modifying the escaping / quoting inside the query but I couldn't come up with the right format.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to put the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` part before `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'`.

```
$query = "  SELECT *
            FROM Catalog
            INTO OUTFILE './catalog.csv'
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not right.It should be:

```
 "SELECT *
        FROM Catalog
        INTO OUTFILE '.\/catalog.csv'
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'           
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
```